# Where can I find the Google Translate API supported languages list?

Tags: google-translate

https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/translate-reference#supported_languages

On this link, it says

> Following is a **partial** list of supported languages and their codes:

What does the word **partial** mean? Are these the only languages supported or can I use more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google: 1) Yes these are the only languages *supported*, 2) Google *may* be able to use more languages. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/translating-text-with-rest) it says: 'Note that other languages which are not listed in this table may be returned (these will be iso639-1 language codes)'. So I suggest to  call the Translate API with all possible [iso639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) codes to try to find out what additional codes are supported.